# c# SMTP mail not supporting single quote in body

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, smtp

i tried to send a mail , when the single quotes is removed works fine, but i need single quotes in the content.

This works But

```
string Body = "<p><b>Hi "
             + dcompanyName + "</b></p>"
             + "<p>Marhaba to edurar.com!!</p>"
             + "<p>Your company  account is active and live.";
```

This Does not Work

```
string Body = "<p><b>Hi "
             + dcompanyName + "</b></p>"
             + "<p>Marhaba to edurar.com!!</p>"
             + "<p>Your company's  account is active and live.";
```

company's  and company (This is the only difference)

Does not trough any error , but mail is not receiving

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] and explain what "does not work" means? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Is it just that you are creating invalid HTML, and happen to send that through mail? Use &lsquo; for a left single quote.

Comment: I check your sending process which one works as your opinion. But it give the error `Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 <customercare@edurar.com>: Sender address rejected: Access denied`

Comment: i tried like this  <p>Your company&lsquo;s  account is active and live.</p>   did not work .. in html viewer displays correctly but mail doesnt work

Comment: sorry i changed the password

Comment: I tired this "<code>Your company's  account is active and live.</code>"    then i got the result, but style was different , is there anything similar

Comment: I tried with the company's. But here it work. may be you are missing anything else like `SMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;`

Comment: That might work , but when i enable it i get  error (The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.)

Comment: Thank you for the support all of you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error is caused by

```
SMTPServer.EnableSsl = false;
```